# How to handle one-to-many and many-to-many relationships in Powershell verbs

Tags: powershell

PoSh has a list of [blessed verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) and recommendations on how the PoSh Cmdlets should be named and act. Say I have two entities: `Environment` and `Item`. I can easily design the cmdlets to manipulate them: `Add-Environment`, `Get-Environment`, `Add-Item`, `Get-Item`, `Set-Item` etc. But now I have a relationship, an `Environment` has zero or more `Item`. What is the blessed Posh way of doing this?

- `Add-EnvironmentItem -Environment $e -Item $i`
- `Set-Item $i -Environment $e`
- ?

And how about many-to-many case, when an `Item` can be in multiple `Environment`?

The question is not about how to implement them, but which is the 'proper' PoSh way of exposing this API.

Comment: A lot of times you'll have collisions with other cmdlets (`Set-Item` is already part of Powershell, for instance).  What I've done in the past is to name my cmdlets according to what is changing.  Instead of `Set-Item` I would have `Set-EnvironmentItems`; `Get-Item` would be `Get-EnvironmentItems` etc.

Comment: I'd say use the most-broad nouns possible.  There are already `-Item` cmdlets and they touch almost any items.

Comment: Regarding this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx), the verb is important, the noun is less. The noun should be significant but not too general as native cmdlets are.

Comment: Nouns should always be singular.

Comment: Nouns are supposed to be very specific also. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878270(v=vs.85).aspx#SD01

Comment: From my point of view, in this context, `Environment` should actually be a item provider similar to the existing [`Environment provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/environment-provider?view=powershell-5.1) this will get rid of the mentioned `Set-Item`, `Get-Item` etc. conflicts...

Comment: Ty all. For the moment I'll go with `Add-EnvironmentItem` (is not really named 'Item', was just an example). The providers path seems promising, but requires extra work which atm I'm not sure is justified for this project.